# Looking at independent, unrelated, values in two columns, find where information matches in both cells and remove duplicates into two new columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Thanks for any help here. I've been racking my brain (and searching online I promise) for a while on this one.

I'm looking at columns A and B that have unrelated information, but sometimes the information in columns A and B are duplicates. For example cell A2 says "Frank" and B2 say "1". then cell A3 says "Frank" and B3 says "1". The information is a duplicate across two columns. The rest of the names in this example can be anything, Frank, Sally, Robert, etc.. and the rest of the numbers in column B can be anything (Image of example attached). If the information is a duplicate I'd like to output a reduced list using two new columns.

These functions need to be operable in real time. As data is added the equations must update in real time. I also can't concatenate because I need info to stay in two columns. I've see a lot of examples of doing this for 1 column of data using an array (see example 2), but I don't know how to build one that considers two columns. 1 column example: =IFERROR(INDEX($T$2:$T$9, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($X$1:X3, $T$2:$T$9), 0)),"") Any ideas how to build this out so it works for two columns?

I'd like to avoid using VBA if possible, but if it's the only way so be it. I want to avoid using VBA because a lot of people touch the spreadsheet and it's a lot easier for me to fix a function than code. Gotta love humans!

Thanks so much for your help!

Robby

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wefut.png) [example2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wju7z.png)

Comment: [Remove Duplicates](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/find-and-remove-duplicates-00e35bea-b46a-4d5d-b28e-66a552dc138d) + [Sort](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sort-data-in-a-range-or-table-62d0b95d-2a90-4610-a6ae-2e545c4a4654)?

Comment: @ DeanOC and @ AdamSmith. Thanks so much for writing back. And so quickly! I think I was too brief in my request. These functions need to be operable in real time. As data is added the equations must update in real time. I also can't concatenate because I need info to stay in two columns. I've see a lot of examples of doing this for 1 column of data using an array, but I don't know how to build one that considers two columns.
1 column example: =IFERROR(INDEX($T$2:$T$9, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($X$1:X3, $T$2:$T$9), 0)),"")

Any ideas how to build this out so it works for two columns?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way that I can think of is:

a) Select your data, and paste elsewhere either on same sheet or a new one.
b) Select one of the cells in the copied data
c) Go to the Data menu tab, and click Remove Duplicates
d) Click OK

Answer (score 0):

Create a new column `C` that concatenates columns `A` and `B`. Then remove duplicates on the basis of column `C`.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CONCATENATE-function-8F8AE884-2CA8-4F7A-B093-75D702BEA31D